# Eigenvalues of triangular block matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to find an expression for determining the eigenvalues of this matrix block
$$
        Acc=\begin{bmatrix}
        A & I  \\
        L & 0 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
$$
where

- $A$ is a matrix of size $n \times n$
- $L$ is a symmetric matrix of size $n \times n$
- $0$ is the null matrix of size $n \times n$
- $I$ is the identity matrix of size $n \times n$

Because the size of these matrices is very large and I have to carry out a program for calculating these eigenvalues I wish I could find a relationship relating the eigenvalues of $Acc$ and the eigenvalues of $A$ and $L$.

Comment: There is some material [here about Determinants of Block Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Block_matrices), and after reading it would seem to me that knowing the invertibility of $A$ is helpful..., though I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks, I had noticed that the question was not clear and I have update it for more details:

Comment: Because the size of this matrix are very large and have to carry out a program for calculating these eigenvalues I wish I could find a relationship Brother eigenvalues of Acc and the eigenvalues of A and L

Comment: with the properties of the determinants of wikipedia I have not been able to get useful results